# Passing parameters to window.open

Tags: php

How i can pass different values when i am calling window.open method.The values are form values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you wish to output values to the JavaScript function window.open. You can echo out the window.open and the various options between the  tags. Something like this:

```
// untested code
$options = "width=$width,height=$height";
$url="www.google.com";

// assuming you have echoed out the JavaScript language tags
echo "window.open('$url', '$options');";
```